# jQuery events, getting correct context of $(this)

Tags: jquery, binding, this, bind, delegation

I need to declare `$featuredImage` outside of mouseenter and mouseleave events with the correct context of `$(this)` to avoid code duplication. As you all know `$(this)` outside of mouseenter/mouseleave is an empty object. I want to bind `$(this)` to the correct context to assign `$featuredImage` just once and access it from both functions, but I don't seem to find the good way to do it.

```
function postThumbOverlay() {

  var $featuredImage;

  $(document).on({
      mouseenter: function(e) {
          // duplicated
          $featuredImage = $(this).parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image' );
          $featuredImage.find('.entry__featured-image--overlay').addClass( 'show--overlay' );
          e.stopPropagation();
      },
      mouseleave: function() {
          // duplicated
          $featuredImage = $(this).parents('.grid').children('.entry__featured-image');
          $featuredImage.find('.entry__featured-image--overlay').removeClass( 'show--overlay' );
      }
  }, '.entry-link');
}
```

The reason I'm not using `.on('hover')` is because doing so stops working after an AJAX call and I need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately.

Comment: Do you mean to say, you want to avoid this line duplication - `$(this).parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image' );` in the events?

Comment: Yes, double assignment of `$featuredImage` — I just don't feel good having this line twice.

Comment: In that case, extract it to a method - `function getFeaturedImageElement($this){ return $this.parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image' );}` and call it in the events - `var $featuredImage = getFeaturedImageElement($(this));`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: And if you really need to avoid querying also, then have a check inside that method - `if(!$featuredImage){ $featuredImage = $this.parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image' ); } return $featuredImage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract it to a method -

```
function getFeaturedImageElement($this){
 return $this.parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image' );
}
```

and call it in the events - `var $featuredImage = getFeaturedImageElement($(this));`

And if you really want to avoid querying the DOM on each events, then have a check inside that method (keeping `$featuredImage` as global as you did) -

```
var $featuredImage;
function getFeaturedImageElement($this){
   if(!$featuredImage){ 
     $featuredImage = $this.parents('.grid').children( '.entry__featured-image'); 
    } 
   return $featuredImage;
}
```

Comment: Add the var declaration and that's it. `var $featuredImage;` Thank you!

Comment: yup, _keeping `$featuredImage` as global as you did_. Will update that in my answer :)